# Some UI widgets don't respond to mouse click in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, logitech-mouse

Some widgets don't respond to mouse click, while others do.  For example, right after boot in gdm3, I can click on my username (to login) or change the volume, but I can't click on the power widget.

Similarly, once logged in (either to Cinnamon or i3-gaps), if I open a terminal, none of the text responds to double-clicks; though I can click and drag to select text.

In Cinnamon, I can't drag windows around the screen.

In Chromium, occasionally, a tab gets into a state where if I click anywhere in the window, it resets the position on the page or goes foward in that tab's history.

I suspect these problems are all related since they all involve clicking.  The problem started about a week ago, and I can't think of what might have changed.  Is there a logfile, configuration file, or utility I should be looking at?

The problem persists across upgrades, including kernel updates.

**Update:**
A different mouse appears to work for all UI elements.  It sounds like a driver issue.  Does this seem like reasonable analysis?  The problematic mouse is the Logitech MX Vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 19.10 is still in pre-alpha. They haven't even yet reached the feature freeze stage yet and from a quick bit of research, there are only daily builds available at the moment.

If there is an issue you are seeing, I would suggest that you raise a bug report with the Ubuntu Devs.

This sort of pre-release software is used for testing, debugging and development of the new distro. There is almost no way for someone on this site to offer any meaningful support for it.

My suggestion would be to check out 19.04 to see if the problem persists, or to keep using a different mouse that you have discovered is working.

Comment: I'm sorry -- you're right.  I'm running 19.04.  I have 19.10 on the brain, but I'm running 19.04.